# Accessing template from subfolder raises problems on relative paths

Tags: pdftex

I would like to use the following folder structure for my project:

```
/template
  template.tex
  template.sty
/doc1
  doc1.tex
/doc2
  doc2.tex
```

The `doc` documents are supposed to access the template that defines part of the preamble. So, `doc` looks like

```
\input{../template/template.tex}
\usepackage{...} %additional packages to load
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

and template.tex looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{template}
\usepackage{...}
```

However, this does not work, because `template.sty` is not found, which seems to be a problem of relative/absolute paths. Is there a nice solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

### Search path at TeX macro level

The macro `\input@path` can contain additional search paths:

```
\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\input@path}{}
\g@addto@macro\input@path{{../template/}}
\makeatother
\input{template.tex}
% ...
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

### Environment variables

Another way is setting the environment variable `TEXINPUTS` to add the path `../template` to the search path for TeX input files, e.g. for TeX Live/Linux/bash:

```
export TEXINPUTS=:../template
```

Also an absolute path could be used instead of the relative path. The colon at the begin (probably semicolon in Windows) says that first the configured paths without `TEXINPUTS` are searched, then TeX looks into `../template`.

### TEXMFHOME

Also the template files could be installed in the home TEXMF tree, example for TeX Live/Linux:

```
~/texmf/tex/latex/template/template.tex
~/texmf/tex/latex/template/template.sty
```